# Save and re-use block for method calls

Tags: ruby

I am calling the   [RestClient::Resource#get(additional_headers = {}, &block)](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/frames)  method multiple times with the same block but on different Resources, I was wondering if there is a way to save the block into a variable, or to save it into a Proc convert it into a block each time.

**Edit:**

I did the following:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new('https://foo.com')
redirect  =  lambda do  |response, request, result, &block|
  if [301, 302, 307].include? response.code
     response.follow_redirection(request, result, &block)
   else
      response.return!(request, result, &block)
   end
end
@resp = resource.get (&redirect)
```

I get: `Syntax error, unexpected tAMPER`

Comment: yes I do , it's just a typo when I edited the original url

Comment: I'm trying to decide if you really want that &block or not. Please edit your question to show what the working (if verbose) code looks like that you're using already.

Comment: Your syntax error is because of the space after `get` on your last line. Remove that space, or the parentheses. (Ruby is trying to send the value inside the parenthesis as the first argument to the method, and an unary ampersand is not valid there.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
foo = lambda do |a,b,c|
   # your code here
end

bar.get(&foo)
jim.get(&foo)
jam.get(&foo)
```

Placing an ampersand in front of an item in a method call, e.g. `a.map!(&:to_i)` calls the `to_proc` method on that object and passes the resulting proc as a block. Some alternative forms of defining your re-usable block:

```
foo = Proc.new{ |a,b,c| ... }
foo = proc{ |a,b,c| ... }
foo = ->(a,b,c){ ... }
```

If you are calling a method with a block and you want to save *that* block for re-use later, you can do so by using an ampersand in the method definition to capture the block as a proc parameter:

```
class DoMany
  def initialize(*items,&block)
    @a = items
    @b = block # don't use an ampersand here
  end
  def do_first
    # Invoke the saved proc directly
    @b.call( @a.first )
  end
  def do_each
    # Pass the saved proc as a block
    @a.each(&@b)
  end
end

d = DoMany.new("Bob","Doug"){ |item| puts "Hello, #{item}!" }

d.do_first
#=> Hello, Bob!

d.do_each
#=> Hello, Bob!
#=> Hello, Doug!
```

Comment: I considered whether to discuss that (and the different behavior of `return` inside both) but decided to keep it simple. However, I wouldn't say that only one or the other is "correct", but rather than they have different behavior which you may or may not want.